# read() system call reads in an extra 0

Tags: c, system-calls

I wrote a function that uses read() system call to read numbers from a file and put them into an array. However, I've noticed that there is always an extra 0 included at the end.

```
       int numberRead = 0;
       int fp;
       char buf[512];
       size_t nbytes = sizeof(buf);
       int n;
       int counter = 0;
       char* ptr;
       size_t curSize = 16;
       int radix = hexFlag ? 16 : 10;


        *array = malloc(curSize * sizeof(*array));

        fp = open(fname, O_RDONLY);      

            if (fp == -1) {
                    return -1;
            }

        while ((n = read(fp, buf, nbytes)) != 0) {
            ptr = strtok(buf, " \n");
            while(ptr) {
                if (counter >= curSize) {
                    curSize += 16;
                    *array = realloc(*array, curSize * sizeof(**array));
                }
                (*array)[counter++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, radix);
                ++numberRead;
                ptr = strtok(NULL , " \n");
            }
        }
```

Is the reason due to `strtok`?

Comment: Don't capitalize C lower-case C identifiers, even in titles. `Read` and `read` are two distinct identifiers.

Comment: Is there extra whitespace at the end of the file, past the \n that terminates the last number?

Comment: is the extra 0 once per line, or once at the end of the whole file?

Comment: @GreenAsJade There isn't a whitespace.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The extra 0 is once at the end of the whole file.

Comment: This code isn't very robust. For one thing, `read()` won't null-terminate your strings, so passing `buf` to `strtok()` like that looks suspicious. Also, unless you're reading in the entire file at once, and any time `read()` fails to read in the number of bytes requested, you might stop reading in the middle of a line, which will throw your logic out.

Comment: `*array = malloc(curSize * sizeof(*array));`  , should be `sizeof **array`

Comment: this line: while ((n = read(fp, buf, nbytes)) != 0) { is not correct because read() can return a error indication(<0); a no bytes read indication (0) and the number of bytes read indication (>0)  therefore, the line should be: while ((n = read(fp, buf, nbytes)) > 0) {

Comment: calls to realloc() should always check the return code BEFORE updating the actual resultant pointer.

Comment: these kind of lines:ptr = strtok(NULL , " \n"); will insert a null at the next char location is a ' ' or a '\n'.  the lines read in will have a '\n' at the end.  However, on certain OSs the '\n' is a multicharacter token. strtok will only replace the first char with '\0'.  so the next call to strtok thinks there is (at least) one more char to gen a pointer to.  then the char * is passed to strtol() which sees no digits so returns 0.  Fix this problem by inserting:  buf[n-1] = '\0'; right after the read()  Note: the -1 points to the '\n' rather than after the '\n'

Comment: this line: (*array)[counter++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, radix); is assuming that each entry in *array[] is a long int. however, the initial malloc assumes the size is '*array' which may be different.   also, **array is not defined anywhere in the presented code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` does not NULL-terminate the buffer it reads into, so this code will likely get an extra number after the end of the last read, which was hanging around in the buffer from the previous read.  Add the line:

```
buf[n] = 0;
```

immediately after the first `while` line that calls read.

In addition, the blocks read by `read` don't necessarily correspond to lines or anything else in particular.  If you're reading from a file, a read call might might return a block of characters that ends in the middle of a multi-digit number, in which case your code will split it into two numbers.  In order to avoid this, you need to not try to tokenize/decode the last few characters read (everything after the last whitespace read), and instead prepend them to the next read.

You end up needing code something like:

```
char buf[1024], *end;
size_t n;
size_t leftover = 0;
while ((n = read(fp, buf+leftover, sizeof(buf)-leftover-1)) > 0 || leftover > 0) {
    buf[leftover+n] = 0;
    ptr = strtok(buf, " \n");
    while(ptr) {
        if (counter >= curSize) {
            curSize += 16;
            *array = realloc(*array, curSize * sizeof(**array));
        }
        (*array)[counter] = strtol(ptr, &end, radix);
        if (end == buf+leftover+n && n > 0) {
            leftover = ptr-end;
            memmove(buf, ptr, leftover);
            break; }
        ++counter;
        ++numberRead;
        ptr = strtok(NULL , " \n");
    }
    if (!ptr) leftover = 0;
}
```